# change global variable when list render in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, v-for

i need to create table with two cycle v-for

```
<tr v-for="(product, index) in mainOrderFood">
 <tr v-for="(toping, i) in mainOrderFood[index]">
</tr>
 </tr>
```

but if you will see on second line on viraible 'index', you'll see that this var don't have value of index, this var watch on global scope.
I try to do like

`<tr v-for="(product, index) in mainOrderFood">
 <tr v-for="(toping, i) in product[index]">
 </tr>
 </tr>`

but var product have same scope like var index

What i need to do to render array like

`mainOrderFood: [
                    {
                      name: 'name',
                      props: [
                        {someprops: ''}
                      ]
                    }
                  ]`

Comment: May be `<tr v-for="(product, index) in mainOrderFood">
 <tr v-for="(toping, i) in product">` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is `(index, product)` actually. But no need for any index in your case.

Suppose your JSON looks like this

```
mainOrderFood: [
                    {
                      name: 'name',
                      props: [
                        {someprops: ''}
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
```

Then you would `v-for` like this:

```
<tr v-for="product in mainOrderFood">
  <tr v-for="toping in product.props">
  </tr>
</tr>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hol42/hph52gdq/4/)

HTML:

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="product in mainOrderFood">
    <th>{{ product.name }}</th>
    <td v-for="toping in product.topings">
      {{ toping }}
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    mainOrderFood: [
      {
        name: 'Spaghetti',
        topings: [
          'Bolognese', 'Cheese'
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Pizza',
        topings: [
          'Pepperoni', 'Funghi'
        ]
      }

    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Property or method "product" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Comment: please look at my example https://jsfiddle.net/hph52gdq/7/
i change td to tr and table fail, why? In project if i do like in example, i'll get an error "Property or method "product" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option"

Comment: Turn on the Javascript Console and read the message. I think vue is not able to have a table in a table with a v-for loop. Which is pretty uncommon and normally not needed. Work with divs and class=row and class=column like in bootstrap.